# Disk Vector Bundle is a Subbundle

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, vector-bundles

I'm having difficultly proving that the disk bundle $D(E)$ of a vector bundle $p: E \to B$ is a subbundle.

The definition I have for $D(E)$ is $D(E) = \{e \in E \ |\ \|e\| \leq 1 \}$

The criteria for $D(E)$ to be a subbundle are:

(i) $D(E)$ is a subspace of $E$

(ii) $D(E) \cap p^{-1}(b)$  is a vector space for ever $b \in B$

(iii) $p|_{D(E)} : D(E) \to B$ is a vector bundle.

My Proof thus far:

(i) is clear from the definition of $D(E)$.

(ii) We know by the definition of vector bundle that $p^{-1}(b)$ is a vector space. However there is no such constraints on $E$ so I cant say that $D(E)$ is a vector space. And this is where I'm having my first issue.

(iii) Not a single clue of how to show this.

Comment: Not all bundles are vector bundles. The disk bundle is not a vector bundle. Do not require the fiber to be a vector space.

Comment: Would the disk bundle then be a fibre bundle?

Comment: Yes, disk bundles and vector bundles are both types of fiber bundles. The main criterion for both is the locally cartesian structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E\overset{\pi}\to B$ is a bundle over base $B$, and $F$ is a subspace of $E$, then $F$ is a subbundle if $F$ is also a bundle over $B$ (so we have $F\overset{p}\to B$) in a compatible way with the bundle structure. In other words so that each fiber of $F$ $p^{-1}(b)$ includes into the corresponding fiber $\pi^{-1}(b)$ of $E$. More abstractly, the following diagram must commute.

[image]

Being a vector bundle is just to say that each fiber is a vector space, in a bundle compatible way. While in some contexts, if someone were to speak of a subbundle of a vector bundle, it may be reasonable to assume they mean vector subbundle, here that is not intended. This subbundle is only a fiber subbundle, not a vector subbundle, since a disk is not a vector space.

So what do you have to prove? Only that for each fiber $p^{-1}(b),$ the fiber of $D(E)$ over $b$ which is $\{e\in E\mid \lVert e\rVert \leq 1 \text{ and } p(e)=b\}$ includes into $p^{-1}(b)$. Which is true by construction.

You also have to check the local triviality condition, which I think is your (iii). In other words, there is a neighborhood $U$ of each point in the base where $D(E)|_U = U\times D(V)$. This is easily seen to be furnished by $D(E_U).$ In other words, the disk bundle of a locally trivial patch of the vector bundle gives a locally trivial patch of the disk bundle.

But since $D(E)$ is not expected to be a vector bundle, we do not need to check the vector space axioms.

Comment: Thanks! As a sub-question, does that then mean that the Thom space of a vector bundle again isn't a vector bundle? I'm saying yes because $Th(E) = D(E)/S(E)$ and if neither $D(E)$ nor $S(E)$ are vector bundles, $Th(E)$ certainly cant be.

Comment: @Niall yes, the Thom space certainly isn't a vector bundle. In fact unlike the sphere bundle and the disk bundle, it isn't a fiber bundle at all, because the quotient operation does not respect fibers. You identify spheres from many different fibers.

Comment: Sorry about the size of this commutative diagram. I cannot figure out how to shrink it. Help!

Comment: In my opinion, the fact that the Thom space is not a vector bundle is basically it's main reason to exist. Just as any vector space is homotopy equivalent to a point, any vector bundle deformation retracts to its base. So the homotopy class of the total space of a vector bundle loses all the topological information about its twists and nontriviality. The Thom space is a way to retain that information.

Comment: I'm currently reading about orthogonal calculus (a paper of that title by Weiss). I think that's why it uses Thom spaces, although I have been stuck on Proposition 1.1 of that paper for a day now!

Comment: I was wondering if you have any good references for Thom spaces?

Comment: I guess one goal is to understand the Pontryagin-Thom construction, which shows how the Thom spectrum is represents cobordism as a cohomology theory. You can find this in Kochman's textbook on Bordism and Stable Homotopy theory, for example.

Comment: You need to check the disk bundle is actually a bundle, i.e. admits local trivializations. This is not very obvious if you don't know that you can find local trivializations of your vector bundle which also trivialize the norm you're using.

Comment: It is true that you can, though. In fact, for two bundles with a metric, if they are isomorphic as bundles, then there is an isomorphism preserving the metric. This is an exercise somewhere in Milnor's characteristic classes book.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the correction @Pedro. I shall edit.